# How can implement keras's merge whith mode of sum

Tags: tensorflow, concatenation, keras

I want implement `merge([a, b], mode='sum')` in tensorflow. What is difference between `mode='sum'` and  `mode='concat'` in keras?

and how can implement `merge([a, b], mode='sum')` in tensorlfow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have two tensors like [1, 2] and [2, 3].  If you use mode = 'concat' it will concatenate them and give [1, 2, 3, 4].  If you use mode = 'sum' it will add them element wise and give a result [1 + 2, 3 + 2] =  [3, 5].  Sum can be implemented using the + operator in tensorflow or the tf.add function.  The concat can be used in tensorflow using the tf.concat function.